# Mapproxy source from WMTS bounding box issue

Tags: mapproxy

I am trying to create an offline version from here:

https://wmts.maptiler.com/aHR0cHM6Ly9ubHMudGlsZXNlcnZlci5jb20vZnBzVVpieHRndGtuL2luZGV4Lmpzb24/wmts

and here is my current config:

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    md:
      title: OS 10k 1888
  tms:
    origin: 'nw'
layers:
  - name: osgb10k1888
    title: OS 10k 1888
    sources: [osgb10k1888_cache]
caches:
  osgb10k1888_cache:
    sources: [osgb10k1888_wmts]
    grids: [webmercator]
sources:
  osgb10k1888_wmts:
    type: tile
    grid: webmercator
    url: https://nls-0.tileserver.com/fpsUZbxtgtkn/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.jpg
grids:
  webmercator:
    base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

This all seems to work fine with the resulting levels and resolutions matching the source correct:

```
Level and Resolutions
Level   Resolution
0   78271.51696402048
1   39135.75848201024
2   19567.87924100512
3   9783.93962050256
4   4891.96981025128
5   2445.98490512564
6   1222.99245256282
7   611.49622628141
8   305.748113140705
9   152.8740565703525
10  76.43702828517625
11  38.21851414258813
12  19.109257071294063
13  9.554628535647032
14  4.777314267823516
15  2.388657133911758
16  1.194328566955879
17  0.5971642834779395
18  0.29858214173896974
```

however the resulting bounding box is:

```
-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244
```

I have tried adding the bbox to the grid based on the source:

```
<ows:LowerCorner>-7.793077 49.852539</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>1.790425 60.894042</ows:UpperCorner>
```

but this the screws up all the resolutions and causes the map to be misaligned

do i need to add all the res into the grid and specify the coords instead of using the web global default?

Comment: The bounding box seems to be correct for the Web Mercator grid but does MapProxy drop the WGS84BoundingBox of the layer "osgb10k1888"? It should be picked automatically https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/blob/1.12.0/CHANGES.txt#L298.

Answer (score 0):

You should add bbox to source.  This will limit request to this bbox.